# jQuery tablesorter "handle", or other click events

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

So I have a basic table.  I allow users to doubleclick on an element in the th to edit the text.  I have since added in the tablesorter plugin, but this now "breaks" the editable text.  Basically tablesorter isn't "honoring" the double click on the interior element.

- Can I define a "sorthandle" for tablesorter?  So instead of clicking
  on the entire th it would only be say a b tag or something?
- Better yet can I find a way to capture doubleclicks on a th and
  handle them separately if necessary (maybe through a method or trigger)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [undocumented option named `cancelSelection`](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html) which you can set to `false` to allow selecting text and double clicking in the table header.